# Pandas read_csv from url returns less number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas read_csv function to directly get data from url. Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
mosa_df = pd.read_csv("https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v2/data?areaType=msoa&metric=newCasesBySpecimenDateRollingSum&format=csv")
print(mosa_df.shape)
```

Output:
(72019, 11)

However if you download same csv manually it is having 210601 records. Is there any limitation on numbers of rows in pandas read_csv? If not, how to get all rows?

Comment: There is no limitation in read_csv, I agree this is weird behaviour.

Comment: I think this is worth opening a ticket for on github.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that pandas has problem to read directly from the URL (maybe a server problem, the server cuts connection and pandas is unable to reconnect).

One solution is to read the source via `requests` and after then put it to pandas:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


url = "https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v2/data?areaType=msoa&metric=newCasesBySpecimenDateRollingSum&format=csv"

data = StringIO(requests.get(url).text)
mosa_df = pd.read_csv(data)
print(mosa_df.shape)
```

Prints:

```
(210785, 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but  it seems like there is some issue with url data at line 72016(when read through pandas) or api returns 72016 rows when read through read_csv method.

Because when I skip 10000 rows from while reading csv, in the output I'm able to read only 62016 rows.
(If there would have been any limitation of read_csv then I should have got 72016 rows from 10001 line)

```
urld = "https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v2/data?areaType=msoa&metric=newCasesBySpecimenDateRollingSum&format=csv"
url_c = pd.read_csv(urld, skiprows=10000, nrows=999999)

url_c.shape 
Output is (62016, 11)
```

Similarly when I'm reading from 72015 row, I'm able to read only single row.

```
url_c = pd.read_csv(urld, skiprows=72015, nrows=999999)

url_c.shape
Output is (1, 11)
```

As expected, when tried reading csv from line 72017, received EmptyDataError.

```
url_c = pd.read_csv(urld, skiprows=72017, nrows=999999)
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```